# Error converting nvarchar to float in Python when using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pyodbc to execute an insert on my SQL Server, but I got an error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

What should I do so I can convert it?

Here is my code:

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password +';Trusted='+Trusted_Connection)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
col_names = ["month", "price", "change"]
df = result

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.emas([month],[price],[change]) values (?,?,?)', 
                    row['month'], 
                    row['price'], 
                    row['change'])
                
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

And my data:

```
month       price   change
1996-01-01  399.45  -
1996-02-01  404.76  1.33 %
1996-03-01  396.21  -2.11 %
1996-04-01  392.85  -0.85 %
1996-05-01  391.93  -0.23 %

i want to convert the price column
```

Comment: Do you really have change with % symbol (1.33 %) ?

Comment: Assuming this is one value of change `404.76  1.33 %` how do you expect it to convert to a numeric value?

Comment: Your data really doesn't make sense. Month `0`? price `1996-01-01`? Change `'399.45  -'`? I'm surprised any of that is working.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't suggest `float`, is the correct data type for *any* of those columns. *Assuming* you're trying to `INSERT` the value `'404.76  1.33 %'` into the column, you have 2 values there, and neither should be `float`. The former should be something like a `decimal(6,2)` (you might want a large precision), and that latter problem more like a `decimal(6,4)`. Don't forgoe, percentages are numbers: `1.33% = 0.0133`. When storing percentages, store them as their decimal value; the application will know what to if you tell it to format it as a percentage.

Comment: im sorry for the confusion,i already edit the question.

Comment: Well I don't see `select cast('-' as float)` working on any SQL Server. Perhaps replace errant data in your Change column with empty strings.

Comment: i already change - to 0,but its still the same..pleasee give me a solution.thank you!